# How to have code that prints to a Device Context save the printout to a BMP file

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am struggling to adapt some code that has printing support to DCs (Device Contexts) and having it print to a Bitmap that can then be saved to disk.

I have tried the following code:

```
// The include files needed for my code
#include "atlimage.h"
#include "afxglobals.h"

// My attempt to get a DC which allows me to draw onto a CBitmap of A4 size
// (21.0x29.7 cm) in 300dpi, or 2480x3508 pixels in 24bit
HBITMAP BMP = CreateBitmap(2480,3508,1,24,NULL);
CBitmap* BitMap = CBitmap::FromHandle(BMP);
CMemDC A4(*CDC::FromHandle(CreateCompatibleDC(NULL)),CRect(0,0,1,1));

// This is where it fails. The SelectObject returns NULL, which means "failed"
// It may be caused by earlier code, but this is where I can detect the problem
// for the first time.
CBitmap* bmp = A4.GetDC().SelectObject(BitMap);
if (bmp == NULL)
    TRACE("Error=%08X\n",GetLastError());
//
// The actual code that does the printing:
//
Graphs[0]->Print(A4.GetDC(),CRect(0,20,75,75));
Graphs[1]->Print(A4.GetDC(),CRect(75,20,100,75));

// And the saving to disk
CImage IMG;
IMG.Attach(*BitMap);
HRESULT res = IMG.Save("D:\\AUDIO.BMP");
IMG.Detach();

// Cleanup
DeleteObject(BMP);
DeleteDC(A4.GetDC());
TRACE("Result=%d\n",res);
```

The first TRACE prints out 00000000 as the error code, so I cannot tell (from this) why it fails.

I'd prefer not to use GDI+ if possible, but if GDI+ (which I don't have experience with) makes it much easier, I won't refuse it. I am using Visual Studio 2008 and cannot update to a newer version (it is part of a much bigger project that will take more time to upgrade to a newer version than I have time right now).

The caveat is that I only have printing routines that take a DC, and am not able to change this, so it must be done via a DC.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the error you refer to happens when you attempt to select the bitmap into the memory DC, the most likely explanation is that they are not compatible.

You have created a memory DC that is compatible with your desktop and that's most likely a 32bpp bitmap. Then you create a 24bpp bitmap, which I think is the problem.

To make sure everything is compatible, try this instead:

```
HDC hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
HBITMAP BMP = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, 2480,3508);
CBitmap* BitMap = CBitmap::FromHandle(BMP);
CMemDC A4(*CDC::FromHandle(hDC),CRect(0,0,1,1));
```

So, you create a bitmap *and* a DC that are compatible with the same original DC. Then the `SelectObject` should not fail.

Maybe update your question or comment on this answer if you don't get further.